# JControllerForm and JControllerAdmin

Tags: joomla-3.x, component

What is the difference between JControllerForm and JControllerAdmin in joomla component?

Answer (score 1):

In simplest terms both are subcontrollers for JControllerLegacy.

JControllerAdmin is essentially the controller for tasks such as displaying a list of records from the database.

JControllerForm is the controller for tasks that act upon data being edited for database entry.

Here is a link to the Joomla Docs that sums it up pretty well [JController Overview](https://docs.joomla.org/JController_and_its_subclass_usage_overview)